# Can i obfuscate an ionic app? if yes how?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, obfuscation, minify

any cordova application is just a native web view and a www folder that contains the entire functionality in HTML javascript and css, so the app is entirely exposed, how can i make it as difficult as possible for anybody to read the app source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really concerned about it my advice is use a professional service to protect your code. E.g. [Jscrambler](https://jscrambler.com)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. There is a cordova-plugin to crypt the html, js, and css files. You find it here: [Cordova crypt file plugin](https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file)

Answer (score 0):

I found it, the problem with angular when got minified is that minification breaks dependency injection.

one solution is to use the string injection based syntax that maps every injected parameter to a string that never gets affected by minification.

example:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller(['$scope', function($scope) { 
   //code
}]);
```

another solution, is to use `ngAnnotate` i prefer to use it with `gulp` task runner

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify= require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('task1', function () {
   return gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
   .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
   .pipe(ngAnnotate())
   .pipe(uglify())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good feature is to hide the location paths of your important scripts. I found a great npm plugin for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/location-hide

It turns

```
<script src="test/folder/sample.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="test/stylesheet/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

into

```
<script src="TNANIuTOLZfmLYwaPDIYhcZDVOWKodqYhysaTeQHFPDhYlDLCOtxZqYmkKAhaSwSgbsYOWlpBzVSBtMZKSfwRqvPSqWVlBBuzHR" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="gyXeFnOEvZbgTjLvdZRnsyrfhaXqffkDjcdATTouqpIenCalLRXKamuXEtiKbPGCsNrdQIaqTMTNWsLyLFuxygKytaruWzSjKYMq" rel="stylesheet">
```

And it generate new jquery include codes like this to include your scripts with javascript in a external file

```
$('[src=\'TNANIuTOLZfmLYwaPDIYhcZDVOWKodqYhysaTeQHFPDhYlDLCOtxZqYmkKAhaSwSgbsYOWlpBzVSBtMZKSfwRqvPSqWVlBBuzHR\']').attr("src", "test/folder/sample.js")  
$('[href=\'gyXeFnOEvZbgTjLvdZRnsyrfhaXqffkDjcdATTouqpIenCalLRXKamuXEtiKbPGCsNrdQIaqTMTNWsLyLFuxygKytaruWzSjKYMq\']').attr("src", "test/stylesheet/perfect-scrollbar.css")
```

Also I would suggest you that you include all of your external javascript codes in 1 single js file. This file you place in the root of your index file that you can make this

```
<script src="./allinone_external_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then make right htaccess that nobody can acces this file. You can also make a fake import script for the source code that every body can see. But this file is only a redirect for the real external js file. you make this multiple times as example + use other obfuscation tools. This will protect you from people searching exploits with your javascript codes. I know its no big deal and maybe you can see the jquery include codes if you know how. But anyway it´s a great protection.

Answer (score 0):

I advise to use babili library (https://github.com/babel/babili)
and form your app so that distribution using electron is made from obfuscated code not from source.

For example package.json contains scripts like this:

```
"main": "release/app.js",
"scripts": {
    "debug": "node ./node_modules/electron/cli.js ./app/app.js",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babili app -d release -D",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/electron ./release/app.js",
    "pack": "./node_modules/.bin/build --dir --ia32"
  }
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

BTW babel supports also ES6/7 obfuscation